# xsd:unique constraint on attribute of two different elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, unique-constraint, xml-validation

Simple problem: I have two different elements which share the same attribute. How can I achieve uniqueness of this attribute along the two different elements?

Example XML snippet:

```xml
<owners>
    <person id="1"/> 
    <company id="2"/>
</owners>
```

In the above code snippet, I want the `id` values to be unique along `person` and `company`. So that person and company does not have the same `id` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're ok with `person/@id` and `company/@id` being unique across *all* elements, simply type those `@id` attributes as `xs:ID`.

If you truly require the scope of uniqueness to be limited to the `@id`s of those two elements within `owners`, use `xs:unique` within `owners` with a `xs:selector/@xpath` of  `person|company`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="owners">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="company" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="personCompanyIdUniqueness">
      <xs:selector xpath="person|company"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If the scope of uniqueness extends to elements higher in your actual hierarchy, raise the `xs:unique` element and adjust the `xs:selector/@xpath` accordingly.